# How to run a program with one command?

Tags: go, scripting

I have an app. There are many .go files, but also there are files with tests.
Of course, the command go run *.go don't work correct.

And now I should write every time something like that: go run fileName.go fileName.go fileName.go and so forth.

Is it possible to run programs with a shorter command ?

Thank You

Comment: Build the program first using `go build`, and run the output. Do not use `go run`

Comment: You can move all but `main.go` files into different folder/package. That will make `go run main.go` work.

Comment: If you *really* want to use go run, you can run `go run .`